# Sonarqube profiles best practices

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to use the default rule set provided by sonarqube (5.1.2) which is collected in the default profile "sonar way". Now I need to add/remove some rules. What is the bets practice here? So far I have created a copy of the default profile and applied my changes there. Then after installing a new plugin I noticed that the default profile has been extend by some rules (obviously the useful ones) of that new plugin. So I need to add them manually to my custom profile. I reckon the same happens with updates of the java plugin.

My questions:

1. Should I work with a copy of the original profile to not pollute it and retain the opportunity to restore it to the factory defaults? (conclusion: manual work every time an update or new plugin comes in)
2. Should work with the original profile? (will it then still be updated without conflicts on new plugins/updates?)
3. Is there a way to work with a profile that is linked to the original profile? (like an overlay filesystem over a read only filesystem => OverlayFS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in profile inheritance: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Non-rule+Profile+Edits+and+Information#Non-ruleProfileEditsandInformation-ProfileInheritance